# How to make a button on a website, when u click it deletes cache, or the links take to the browser cache setting

Tags: web, caching, browser, browser-cache

I am not developer, but I would like to know. Is it possible or not..

How to make a button on a website, when u click it deletes cache, or the links take to the browser cache setting.

Same like the link opens new browse, same kind of logic.

It helps every time website having any update.

I am not developer, I don't know about coding at all.